# Script is working fine with IE but not with Chrome? mvc.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is a script :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

var pageSize = 10;
var pageIndex = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    GetData();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == 
           $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            GetData();
        }
    });
});

function GetData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/home/GetData',
        data:{"pageindex":pageIndex,"pagesize":pageSize},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#container").append("<h2>" + 
                    data[i].CompanyName + "</h2>");
                }
                pageIndex++;
            }
        },
        beforeSend : function () {
            $("#progress").show();
        },
        complete : function () {
            $("#progress").hide();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error while retrieving data!");
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried removing the type="text/javascript". What might be the possible issue, and how to fix scripting issues on diff browsers. 
How can I use this script in case of tight coupling like, DisplayFor(x => x.name) in mvc .net?

Comment: what is the problem ? Did you check the console of chrome ? Put the error message and a console screenshot. Otherwise no will be able to help you.

Comment: Console of chrome ? Okay, I need to check what is that :(

Comment: please add debugger; in your code and tell us what is the problem

Comment: I checked into Inspect element and console it is all blank. Did you mean the same console ?

Comment: @prime I added debugger, that debugger hits only when I use IE. ( For all scripts ) and on IE this scripts works fine. In MVC project, how do I add debugger to script ? I guess I need to learn that one

Comment: Just add debugger;  for ex: function GetData() { debugger;  $.ajax({ ...

Comment: It doesn't hit when I use chrome., I am using VS13

Comment: ok, you can test it by adding alert in the first of your function

Comment: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/6d19edd9-7582-4caf-b254-73deca44ecfb.aspx here you can see in detail